# Need help counting oven time

Tags: calculus

I need to keep my sausages in 175 °C oven for 15 minutes. But I want to cook them with my fries at the same time. These fries need to be in 225 °C oven for 20 minutes. When should I put sausages in there with the fries so they both get cooked?

Comment: Ideally, since they require different temperatures, you would cook them separately.

Comment: What assumptions could be made? Is the length of sausage cooking depended on the temperature? What relation? Could we have the fries cooked for longer time at 175 C? What relation?